# WebWorks Web Inspector - Unexpected response code: 426

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-webworks

I am trying to use Web Inspector in a browser on Blackberry 7.0 (BB Torch 9860) and in Chrome I've got the following error when loading it:

```
Unexpected response code: 426   :1337:1
```

Any ideas why it happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar issue but managed to get it working by switching browsers.

Try it in safari instead of chrome. see step 7 of http://www.berryreview.com/2011/11/18/blackberry-os-7-web-inspector-easily-debug-blackberry-websites-webworks-browser-apps/

I'm not really sure why mostly because I don't care enough to find out why but hopefully this solves your problem

Comment: yes, it works in Safari. But with Bold 9900 it still doesn't work anywhere. I suppose I have to update handheld software.

Comment: if the web inspector is blank try refreshing your browser.  steps to get it work are: 1) on BB turn Dev tool on, 2) open up url in safari, 3) refresh browser and 4) debug away

Answer (score 1):

This was also giving me a lot of grief. I have an older Blackberry running version 7.0 something that I am testing on that would not attach to the web inspector in neither latest Chrome or Safari (version 6), both displaying the blank page with a search field in the top right and two controls, bottom left.

I finally managed to get the web inspector running, by installing the older Safari 5 and loading the web inspector page from that.

I downloaded it from here: http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1531